# 3TB usb drive for ubuntu and windows

Tags: mount, windows, ntfs-3g

I have a 3TB usb harddisk that I wish to switch between windows, but most of the time Ubuntu 12.04 server. But whatever I try, it can't be *correctly* recognized by both systems.

The last *closest* try I have done by now is: [I believe i] format the drive in windows and add a drive letter. Then unplug the drive and plug it in the Ubuntu system. Then run the command: `mount ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/usb1`.

But that gives 2 issues:

- Most important one, files I add to the drive in windows aren't there on Ubuntu, and files I add on Ubuntu are missing in windows.
- The other issue is; the drive isn't recognized in Ubuntu (no /dev/sdb1 exists, however /dev/sdb does). No UUID is present for sdb1. However mounting manually with /dev/sdb1 is no problem. But adding it to fstab (I tried to mount it with /dev/sdb1 instead of UUID) gives me the following error on system startup: `HDIO_GET_IDENTITY failed for '/dev/sdb'`

Can't find an issue on the web. looks like it should work at once without problems. Can someone put me in the correct direction?

some extra info:

`fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 3000.6 GB, 3000592977920 bytes 255 heads, 63
sectors/track, 364801 cylinders, total 5860533160 sectors Units =
sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
```

`blkid`

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="ec280792-e09f-4957-bb9e-5fc2cca2a297" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda5: UUID="bf95d0b6-dd74-44b2-b7b5-9f2d64a07aa4" TYPE="swap"
```

`parted -l`

```
Error: /dev/sdb: unrecognised disk label
```

`lshw`

```
 *-scsi:2
      physical id: 5
      bus info: usb@1:2
      logical name: scsi6
      capabilities: emulated scsi-host
      configuration: driver=usb-storage
    *-disk
         description: SCSI Disk
         product: External USB 3.0
         vendor: Toshiba
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@6:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/sdb
         version: 0201
         serial: 76B67345
         size: 2794GiB (3TB)
         capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
         configuration: ansiversion=6
       *-volume UNCLAIMED
            description: EFI GPT partition
            physical id: 1
            bus info: scsi@6:0.0.0,1
            capacity: 2047GiB
            capabilities: primary nofs
```

Comment: What is the file system of disk? Is this output of command is complete because it sdb is not here.

Comment: Windows is designed to only boot from internal drives. And Windows will only boot in UEFI boot mode from gpt partitioned drives. Any drive over 2TB must be gpt. If drive came pre-partitioned or partitioned from Windows it may be a hybrid or vendor proprietary configuration to work with XP. Best to just have gpt. Post this: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: @puneetDixit yes it is complete. thats the strange thing about it. it doesnt return a UUID. And like oldfred asked, parted -l gives an error as well. (only past the relevant part (skiped pasting sda))

Comment: @oldfred GPT for above 2TB was clear for me by now. I absolutly parted and formated the drive. from ubuntu (with parted command) and in windows (disk management). Also runned a diskcheck in windows (readed somewhere that that could fix it). The drive is only holds data, no operationsystem (if you did mean that with "boot")

Comment: If using with Windows 8 or later, it may be left in a hibernated state (fast start up in Windows). Then the Linux NTFS driver will not see it. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation